# package XLConnect and xlsx

Tags: r, excel, list

I want to read all excel sheets into a R list df. The code I'm using is:

```
file <- file.choose()
name <- basename(file)
require(XLConnect)
wb <- XLConnect :: loadWorkbook(name)
lst <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))
```

BUT, after that I need to use package 'xlsx'. If I go back to use the above code to read file, I got error message after `lst <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb))`:

> Error in wb$getNumberOfSheets : Method undefined for class 'workbook'

btw, if I use `wb <- loadWorkbook(name)`, I got the error message

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>         unable to find an inherited method for function ‘readWorksheet’ for signature ‘"jobjRef", "list"’

Any method can make the two packages work together, OR, other method to read excel file with multiple sheets to a df list? Much appreciate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue here is that you seem to have loaded two packages that have the same function names. Both `xlsx` and `XLConnect` offer the functions `loadWorkbook` and `getSheets`. That is where most of your errors are coming from.
As a result, you are calling `loadWorkbook` and `getSheets` and providing them with arguments whose object types these functions do not expect.

You're better off working with just one of them to get your desired list of data.frames. I would recommend sticking with `XLConnect` for now, until you need something specific from the `xlsx` package.

The following is a tweaked version of the code you tried to run above:

```
require(XLConnect)


file_name <- file.choose()
base_name <- basename(file_name)

wb <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook(base_name)
lst <- XLConnect::readWorksheet(wb, sheet=XLConnect::getSheets(wb))
```

The list `lst` should contain data.frames matching the data present in the sheets inside your workbook.

If you wish to save your list of data.frames in a new excel workbook, you can use the `writeWorksheet` function. You will need to first open the workbook or create it, if it does not already exist. Then you create the sheet names where the data will go. At this point, you can add the dataframes to their corresponding sheets. Once that's done, then you can save the workbook.

```
new_wb = loadWorkbook('aaa.xlsx', create=TRUE)
createSheet(new_wb, names(lst))
writeWorksheet(new_wb, data=lst, sheet=names(lst))
saveWorkbook(new_wb)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: OP can also use the `::` notation, e.g. `XLConnect::loadWorkbook`, respective `xlsx::loadWorkbook`, to differentiate the functions.

Comment: @abdou Thank you! I also need to write df list to a new excel file with different sheets (each sheet corresponds to a element of the list.). Currently, I'm using 
lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.xlsx(lst[[x]], 'aaa.xlsx', sheetName=x, append=TRUE)). I don't know how to use XLConnect to accomplish that. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @XiLiu please see the edits. You could also use `::` with `xlsx` by doing: `lapply(names(lst), function(x) xlsx::write.xlsx(lst[[x]], 'aaa.xlsx', sheetName=x, append=TRUE))`.

Comment: @Abdou Both work! Obviously, I forgot the "XLConnect" in the " sheet=XLConnect::getSheets(wb))" part. Thank you!!